# PHP encryption via phpBolt

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I encrypted a laravel project and it was working good in my PC, but after uploading to the server i got the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bolt_decrypt() in xxxxxx/app/Http/Kernel.php:2 Stack trace: #0 xxxxxx/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include() #1 xxxxxx/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/stsgulf/p...') #2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\Http\\Kernel') #3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('App\\Http\\Kernel') #4 xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(752): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Http\\Kernel') #5 xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Kernel') #6 xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Http\\Kernel', in xxxxxx/app/Http/Kernel.php on line 2
```

**I tried to move it to another PC i got the same error**

Note: I also added the bolt extension to the new PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, by installing xampp on "C" directory